# I need to refresh the checkout page if someone changes the zip code

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

As per one of issues I am facing I need to refresh the entire checkout page if anyone makes the change in the zip code .
Kindly let me know how can this be done

Comment: What do you mean with "refresh"? Page reload?

Comment: Why? To do what? WooCommerce has hooks you can use to selectively upload parts of the checkout. So a full page refresh shouldn’t be necessary.